# BasicEditField BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want a `BasicEditField` with rounded border and white background fill.

This is my code

```
public class BasicField extends BasicEditField {

    XYEdges padding = new XYEdges(0,0,0,0);
    int color = Color.BLACK;
    int lineStyle = Border.STYLE_SOLID;
    int Width, Height;
   Border roundedBorder = BorderFactory.createRoundedBorder(padding, color, lineStyle);
    public BasicField()
    {
          super(BasicEditField.NO_NEWLINE);
            //this.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);  
            //this.setBorder(roundedBorder);
    }

     public int getPreferredWidth()  
     {  
            int labelWidth = getFont().getAdvance(getLabel()) - 1; 
         Width = Graphics.getScreenWidth() -150;
         return Width;  
     }  

     public int getPreferredHeight()  
     {  
         return 10;  
     }  

     public void paint(Graphics g) {


         int currCol = g.getColor();
         g.setBackgroundColor( Color.WHITE );
         g.fillRect(0, 0, getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight() );
         g.clear();
         g.setColor( Color.NAVY );
          super.paint( g );
        }
    protected void layout( int maxWidth, int maxHeight )
    {
        super.layout( getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight() ); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go -

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

border.png:

[image: border]

MyEdit.java:

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.*;

public class MyEdit extends UiApplication {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyEdit app = new MyEdit();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public MyEdit() {
        pushScreen(new MyScreen());
    }
} 

class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
    Border myBorder = BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder( 
        new XYEdges(20, 16, 27, 23), 
        Bitmap.getBitmapResource("border.png"));

    BasicEditField myField = new BasicEditField(TextField.NO_NEWLINE) {
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            if (getTextLength() == 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
                g.drawText("Search", 0, 0);
            }

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    public MyScreen() {
        myField.setBorder(myBorder);
        setTitle(myField);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Friend... try this code.....

```
class BasicEditScreen extends MainScreen                                                                                                                                                                                              
{                                                                                                                       
    public BasicEditScreen()                                                                                                                    
    {

        add(new BasicField(200, 40, FIELD_LEFT, "Enter here..", "horizontal"));                                                   
    }

}
```

---

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;

public  class BasicField extends Manager 
{

    private int managerWidth;
    private int managerHeight;
    private int inactiveBorderColor = Color.GRAY;
    private int activeBorderColor = Color.GREENYELLOW;
    private int borderColor = inactiveBorderColor;
    private int backgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
    private int arcWidth;

    private VerticalFieldManager vfm ;
    private EditField editField;
    int nn =1;
    int count=0;

    public BasicField(int width, int height,  long style, final String hint,String type_horizontal_vertical)
    {

        super(style | NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL | NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);

        if(type_horizontal_vertical.equalsIgnoreCase("Horizontal"))
            vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | USE_ALL_WIDTH );
        if(type_horizontal_vertical.equalsIgnoreCase("Vertical"))
            vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL| USE_ALL_WIDTH | USE_ALL_HEIGHT);
        managerWidth = width;
        managerHeight = height;
        long innerStyle = style & (READONLY | FOCUSABLE_MASK); // at least
        if (innerStyle == 0) 
        {
            innerStyle = FOCUSABLE;
        }
        if(style==EditField.FILTER_EMAIL)
        {
            innerStyle = EditField.FILTER_EMAIL;
        }
        if(style==EditField.FILTER_INTEGER)
        {
            innerStyle = EditField.FILTER_INTEGER;
        }
        editField = new EditField("", null, EditField.DEFAULT_MAXCHARS, innerStyle)
        {
            public void paint(Graphics g)
            { 
                if(editField.getText().length()==0)
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                    g.drawText(hint,5,2);
                    super.paint(g);
                }
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                super.paint(g);
            }
        };

        arcWidth = editField.getFont().getHeight() & 0xFFFFFFFE; // make it even

        add(vfm);
        vfm.add(editField);
    }

    public void setFont(Font font)
    {
        super.setFont(font);
        editField.setFont(font);
        arcWidth = editField.getFont().getHeight() & 0xFFFFFFFE;
        updateLayout();
    }

    public void setBorderColors(int inactive, int active) 
    {
        inactiveBorderColor = inactive;
        activeBorderColor = active;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBackgroundColor(int bgColor)
    {
        backgroundColor = Color.AQUA;
        invalidate();
    }


    public String getText()
    {
        return editField.getText();
    }

    public void setText(String newText) 
    {
        editField.setText(newText);
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() 
    {
        return managerWidth;
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() 
    {
        return managerHeight;
    }

    protected void sublayout(int w, int h) 
    {
        if (managerWidth == 0) 
        {
            managerWidth = w;
        }
        if (managerHeight == 0) 
        {
            managerHeight = h;
        }
        int actWidth = Math.min(managerWidth, w);
        int actHeight = Math.min(managerHeight, h);
        layoutChild(vfm, actWidth - arcWidth, actHeight - arcWidth); 
        setPositionChild(vfm, arcWidth / 2, arcWidth / 2);  
        setExtent(actWidth, actHeight);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics g) 
    {

        int prevColor = g.getColor();
        int myWidth = managerWidth;
        int myHeight = managerHeight;
        g.setColor(backgroundColor);
        g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight, arcWidth, arcWidth);
        g.setColor(borderColor);

        g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight, 10,10);
        g.drawRoundRect(1, 1, myWidth - 2, myHeight - 2, 10-2, 10-2);
        g.setColor(prevColor);

        super.paint(g);
    }



    private void adjustBorderColor() 
    {
        int nextColor;
        if (editField.isFocus()) 
        {
            nextColor = activeBorderColor;
        }
        else 
        {
            nextColor = inactiveBorderColor;
        }
        if (borderColor != nextColor) 
        {
            borderColor = nextColor;
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```